# Should have got div result with proper message (or) check the logic for Pre paid FullTalkTime connection type

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is a code I've written to calculate charges for a connection service.
inorder: javascript,css,html

// requirements
:Customer name should contain only alphabets and space.
· Mobile Number should be of 10 digits and should start with 9/8/7.
. The Connection Type needs to be Pre or Post. . The scheme names are Local, STD and FullTalkTime.
. The Connection Duration can be specified ranging from 1 to 12 months :On clicking connection bill amount button, the connection bill amount should be calculated.
:formula to calculate the Total Monthly Rental Cost:Total Monthly Rental Cost = ( duration * Cost per month ) + Monthly Rental

Errors I'm getting:

1. output of this is clumsy and not aligned - its throwing "check with requirements for css"
2. Should have got div result with proper message (or) check the logic for Pre paid FullTalkTime connection type
3. Should have got div result with proper message (or) check the logic for Pre paid Local connection type
4. Should have got div result with proper message (or) check the logic for Post paid Local connection type

```js
function TotalRental() {
    var month = document.getElementById("duration").value;
    var conn = document.getElementById("connectiontype");
    var ctt = conn.options[conn.selectedIndex].value;
    var cm = 0;
    var mr = 0;

    if (document.getElementById("scheme1").checked) {
        cm = 200;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("scheme2").checked) {
        cm = 350;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("scheme3").checked) {
        cm = 500;
    }

    if (ctt == "Pre") {
        mr = 75;
    }

    if (ctt == "Post") {
        mr = 150;
    }
    
    var resultt = ((month * cm) + mr);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The Total Monthly Rental Cost is Rs. " + resultt;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #EED426
}

h1 {
    color: #006666;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ACTB Connection Portal</h1>

    <form>
        <label>Customer Name</label><input type="text" name="custname" id="name" placeholder="Enter the customer name"
            required>
        <br>
        <label>Customer Email</label><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" required>
        <br>
        <label>Mobile Number</label><input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter the Mobile Number" max="10"
            pattern="[789]{1}[0-9]{9}" required>
        <br>
        <label>Type of Broadband</label>
        <select name="conntype" id="connectiontype" value="connectiontype" required>
            <option id="Pre" value="Pre">Pre</option>
            <option id="Post" value="Post">Post</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Scheme Name</label>

        <input type="radio" name="scheme" id="scheme1" value="Local">Local
        <input type="radio" name="scheme" id="scheme2" value="STD">STD
        <input type="radio" name="scheme" id="scheme3" value="FullTalkTime">FullTalkTime
        <br>
        <label>Connection Duration</label><input type="number" name="duration" id="duration" min="1" max="12"
            required><br>
        <span>
            <input type="button" value="calculate bill" onclick="TotalRental()" name="submit">
            <button type="Reset" name="clear">Reset</button></span><br>

        <div id="result" name="result"></div><br>
    </form>
    <table name="Rental Cost Table" border="1" id="rentalcost" value="rentalcost">

        <tr>
            <td><strong>Connection Type</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Call Limit</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Monthly Rental</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pre</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Post</td>
            <td>Unlimited</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 0):

The changes you need is in the javascript,  always  radioobject.checked has the default value as false. So you need to check it whether it is true. Like -

```
If(document.getElementById("scheme1").checked==true) {
    //statement 
}
```

The same goes for the other if statements.